# Centralizers of Elements in the Free Group

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, free-groups

Let $F_n$ be the nonabelian free group on $n$ generators. According to what I have been reading from various sources online, the centralizer of some element $h \in F_n$, denoted as $C_{F_n}(h)$, is an infinite cyclic group. Furthermore, every subgroup of $F_n$ is itself a free group, which would seem to suggest that $C_{F_n}(h)$ is a free group on one generator. Any free group on one generator is necessarily abelian.

So my question is, am I correct in concluding that $C_{F_n}(h)$ is in fact an abelian subgroup of $F_n$ for every $h \in F_n$?

Comment: Yes, you are...

Comment: I have very little experience with free groups, but I would expect the centralizer of an element $h$ to contain the bare minimum it could possibly contain, namely, $\langle h \rangle \cong \Bbb Z$. Just another reason to expect "the free group on one generator."

Comment: that makes a ton of sense @pjs36

Comment: "Infinite cyclic group" already means $\mathbb{Z}$, which is the free group on one generator and abelian.

Comment: @pjs36 That is not quite right because the centralizer of $h^2$ contains $h$, which is not in $\langle h^2 \rangle$. In general the centralizer of $h (\ne 1)$ is $\langle g \rangle$ where $h=g^k$ with $k$ maximal.

Comment: @DerekHolt I hadn't even considered that, d'oh!